# div needs to have a right margin while filled with white and adjacent to another div

Tags: html, css

Essentially, I have a div that needs to go next to another element on a page. Furthermore, this div needs to be fully colored in white and a paragraph on top of it for information. Here is a link to what I see and the circled area is what I need the heading to fill. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPsO4.jpg

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2E2E46;
}

#nav_top {
    background-color: #000000;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 75px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: 0%;
}

#h1 {
    margin-left: 76px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}

#help_nav {
    float: right;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

#logo {
    width: 59px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
#pagetitle {
    margin-left: 75px;
    background-color: #553D53;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 75px;
    opacity: 1;
    float: none;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 75px;
}

#bgc {
    margin-right: 75px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
}

#wires {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 300px;
}

#titletext {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

#titlehead {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

#subtext {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 105px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 2;
    font-size: xx-small;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidenav {
    padding-top: 427px;
    padding-left: 75px;
}

#navbartitle {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 55px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 355px;
    margin-right: 75px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: contain;
    background: white;
    float: none;
    padding-right: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    margin-top: 428px;
}

#subtexttext {
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="nav_top">
        <div id="help_nav">
            <h2><a href="#" style="color:white">Contact</a> | <a href="#" style="color:white">Help</a> | <a href="#" style="color:white">Report</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/Asset_1.png" width="50" height="58" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="h1">
            <h1>A.H.E.M</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="titletext">
        <h2 id="titlehead">This is the content for Layout H2 Tag</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="subtext">
        <h2 id="subtexttext">This is the content for Layout H2 Tag</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="pagetitle">
        <img id="wires" src="images/wires.png" width="275" height="303" alt="" />
        <img id="bgc" src="images/Artboard 1.jpg" width="150" height="86" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="sidenav">
        <h2 id="navbartitle"> Navigation</h2>
        <img src="images/nav2.png" width="280" height="648" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2> Dogs</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

[**Working JS Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4myfvwj7/)

div named content and div name sidenav are next to each other on the same page.
I need #content to be indented on the right by 75px and 355px on the left to line up with the other parts. If I set it to absolute, I can position the div correctly but it wont fill the entire background. If it's static it will fill to right size but then it cannot sit next to #sidenav. I've read a lot of different ideas and solutions but simply can't get it to work.

I am pretty new to HTML and CSS so I apologize if this an easy question but I've been at this two hours. All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: in your css you can combine your background properties for `#content` like this: `background: white repeat;`. The `background-size: contain;` is for images and `background-position: 0% 0%;` is default

Comment: `position: absolute ` takes your element out of the page flow. I would allmost never recomend using this for elements that are not supposed to be ontop af a different element. Try loocking into flexbox. Its one of the best ways to order different elements. Here is an easy guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I find this a bit confusing. it would be easier if you show a layout with the desired output.

Comment: also if you end up using `position: absolute`. Don't position them with margain. Simply use `top: 428px` `left: 355px`

Comment: @Becky https://imgur.com/wAtkvBl here's a link to what my full layout is. The blue circle is what needs to be filled in

Comment: I think you need to learn about flexboxes and displaying inline-block over floating divs. I'd be happy to show you, but I will need an image to show us what you really want (nvm you just posted it ;) I check this out)

Answer (score 0):

Following might help you, Please read through what is absolute and relate positions,

https://jsfiddle.net/psv6xo9w/

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #2E2E46;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 75px;
}

#nav_top {
    background-color: #000000;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 75px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-indent: 0;
    line-height: 0%;
}

#h1 {
    margin-left: 76px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}

#help_nav {
    float: right;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: small;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

#logo {
    width: 59px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
#pagetitle {
    background-color: #553D53;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 1;
    float: none;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}

#bgc {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
}

#wires {
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

#titletext {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    width: 100%;
}

#titlehead {
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

#subtext {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 2;
    font-size: xx-small;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

#sidenav {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 29px;
    width: 25%;
    background: #696969;
}

#navbartitle {
    margin-left: 55px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: xx-large;
}
#content {
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: contain;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    top: 1px;
    width: 70%
}

#subtexttext {
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.row {
  float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_top">
        <div id="help_nav">
            <h2><a href="#" style="color:white">Contact</a> | <a href="#" style="color:white">Help</a> | <a href="#" style="color:white">Report</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/Asset_1.png" width="50" height="58" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="h1">
            <h1>A.H.E.M</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="pagetitle">
          <div id="titletext">
              <h2 id="titlehead">This is the content for Layout H2 Tag</h2>
          </div>
          <div id="subtext">
              <h2 id="subtexttext">This is the content for Layout H2 Tag</h2>
          </div>
          <img id="wires" src="images/wires.png" width="275" height="303" alt="" />
          <img id="bgc" src="images/Artboard 1.jpg" width="150" height="86" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="sidenav">
          <h2 id="navbartitle"> Navigation</h2>
          <img src="images/nav2.png" width="280" height="648" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h2> Dogs</h2>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
```